# Javascript 2.0 classes

Tags: javascript, class

I'm reading a book "How to Do Everything with JavaScript" and I'm currently learning how to define classes. The book says there are 2 ways. first using functions in javascript 1.x. second, using class in javascript 2.0.

what I'm trying is:

```
class Car {
    var Make : String;
    var Model : String;
    var Year : Integer;
    var Color : String;
    var FullName : String;

    function Car (make, model, year, color) {
        this.Make = make;
        this.Model = model;
        this.Year = year;
        this.Color = color;
        this.FullName = this.Year + " " + "<b>" + this.Make + "</b> " + this.Model;
    }
}

var mySUV = new Car("Toyota", "4Runner SR5",2001, "Thundercloud");
document.write ("I drive a " + mySUV.FullName);
```

The code is not working when I'm trying to run it. I use komodo editor to develop and when I define a class like I mentioned before, It gives me a warning "strict warning: class is a reserved identifier".

Is there something wrong with the code? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What JavaScript 2 runtime are you using?

Comment: I use Komodo editor and  Firefox/3.5.5? Is that what you mean by Javascript runtime?

Comment: Firefox includes the runtime.

Answer (score 10):

JavaScript 2.0 aka ECMAScript 4 was abandoned in 2008, before it was ever released. There will never be a class-based version of ECMAScript. Which is a good thing.

Comment: I personally kinda liked ES4.

Comment: There were some good ideas in it. But it had 3 major problems: 1) it simply wasn't JavaScript. It might have been an nice *new* language, but it wasn't JavaScript. 2) Simply grabbing every single feature ever invented from every language ever created and dumping them into one language is *not* how you design a good language. 3) You don't do original research in an industry standards body. Gradual typing is cool, but it is *still* an open research problem in 2010. You simply don't put an open research problem into the most widely used programming language on the planet.

Comment: *"It might have been an nice new language"* - It actually is, it's called ActionScript 3 ;)

Comment: No, there will be a class-based version of ECMAScript. It's called ECMAScript 6. Also, much ECMAScript 4 is already implemented in ActionScript 3.

Comment: And JavaScript 2.0 was never abandoned, it's still going to be made and implement ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @wizlb: Several reasons. One, both prototype-based delegation and class-based inheritance are perfectly reasonable approaches. (See the Treaty Of Orlando for details.) But *both* at the same time in the same language? Not so much. Two, "class" is a pretty simple design pattern in a prototype-based language, "prototype" is a pretty complicated design pattern in a class-based language. This seems to suggest that prototypes are in some sense more powerful than classes, so why would you want something less powerful in your language? Three, Alan Kay invented OO and he doesn't like classes.

Comment: @wizlb: There's a nice quote by Mads Torgersen, one of the designers of C#: "I wouldn't want to use a language that has every feature I want to use in a language". You don't make languages better by adding features. Often, you don't even make them more powerful. Just more complex. (You make them good by choosing a small set of powerful core abstractions, and then allow the *programmers* to make the language better through libraries.) You can implement classes in ECMAScript in about a couple dozen lines of code. Is it really worth it to massively complicate the spec to save those few lines?

Comment: @wizlb: Note that I have nothing against classes. I use Ruby, Smalltalk, Newspeak, Scala, all of which are class-based. I only have something against cramming classes into a language which has absolutely no need for them. What ECMAScript *needs* is to file off the rough edges of its prototype-based OO model (and that is mostly done with ECMAScript 5.1), not cram a completely different, second OO model in there.

Comment: If they added classes and you never used them, would you know the difference? You're right, class-based inheritance is a subset of prototypical inheritance. So, if you can already do class-based inheritance with the prototype model, what's the problem with adding a simple keyword in order to standardize the approach? Nothing. It just offends your sense of decorum.

Comment: The fact that developers so often feel the need to implement class-based inheritance on their own is a sure sign that the language needs to help them achieve that goal in a standard way that allows everyone to share code easier instead of repeating ourselves over and over. So, sorry but I disagree.

Comment: "There will never be a class-based version of ECMAScript." I come from the future. We have classes now!

Comment: @grantman16: ES-Harmony classes are *very* different from ES4 classes. ES-Harmony classes are merely a thin layer of syntactic sugar over a common pattern of using prototypal inheritance. ES4, at least some iterations of it, proposed adding a completely separate class-based OO model *in addition* to the prototype-based OO model. ES-Harmony classes OTOH are built *on top* of the prototypal OO model.

Comment: @JörgWMittag still, your post is confusing, since ES6 is out now and has something called "classes". Maybe edit your post to make it about "ES4-draft style classes"?

Answer (score 4):

The latest version of JavaScript is 1.8.1. If by JavaScript 2, you mean ECMAScript 6 (or 4), there's no engines that implement it yet. You can convert it to ECMA-262 code using [Mascara](http://www.mascaraengine.com/).

To everyone else: Why are you people saying JavaScript 2 is dead? There were plans to implement ECMAScript 4 in JavaScript 2 and *that* has been abandoned. JavaScript 2 will most likely be an implementation of ECMAScript 6 but it isn't itself ECMAScript 6.

Comment: This post is misleading, parts of ECMAScript 6 have been implemented in e.g. Babel.

Comment: This post wasn't wrong 7 years ago when I wrote it. ECMAScript 6 is getting support in most JS engines nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to merge things together, and clean up Zain's answer.

As Jörg W Mittag mentioned, ES4/JS2 is dead, so let's do it the ES3/JS1 way.

To compress Zain's answer:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
function Car(make, model, year, color) {
  this.Make = make;
  this.Model = model;
  this.Year = year;
  this.Color = color;
  this.FullName = this.Year + " " +
  "<b>" + this.Make + "</b> " +
  this.Model;
}
var mySUV = new Car("Toyota", "4Runner SR5",2001, "Thundercloud");
document.write ("I drive a " + mySUV.FullName);
```

If you wanted to do this without functions you could say:

```
var Car = {
  Make : String,
  Model : String,
  Year : Integer,
  Color : String,
  FullName : String
}
```

But then you would have to manually set the values, so no, there isn't really a good way of making a complex object without the use of a function.

Comment: `: String` was I think supposed to be ActionScript type notation, it doesn't exist in JavaScript.

Comment: Nope, I checked it in the closure compiler. I was amazed too.

Comment: JS2 can't be dead before it's even started. JS2 is going to be ES6.

Answer (score 1):

No mainstream browser supports the JavaScript 2.0 syntax today.

[Mascara](http://www.mascaraengine.com) is a tool which will translate JavaScript 2.0 syntax (or something close to it) into ordinary JavaScript which will run in any browser, so you get classes, type-checking etc. but don't have to worry about compatibility.

Also, ActionScript 3 which is supported by Flash has a syntax close to JavaScript 2.

Note that JavaScript 2 is not an official standard, rather it is the Mozilla specific name for a proposed new version of JavaScript. The official vendor-neutral name for the JavaScript standard is ECMAScript.

The version of ECMAScript which is supported by mainstream browsers today is ECMAScript 3.

The proposed extensions, equivalent to what is called JavaScript 2.0 and Actionscript 3, was at one point called ECMAScript 4.

However the proposed ECMAScript 4 spec was felt by some vendors to be too ambitious, and it was decided to evolve the language iterative through less-ambitious steps. Hence the big ES4 spec was abandoned, and a new version called ECMAScript 5 which incorporated a small number of the features proposed for ES4 was created instead as a first step (notably, classes and type-annotations is not part of ES5). ES5 have been officially released, but is not yet fully supported by browsers. Work is ongoing on the next version, code named "Harmony", but which will probably end op being called ES6. It is yet unclear whether ES6 will include a syntax for classes.

The bottom line: you cannot run JavaScript 2 directly in any mainstream browser today, and it may take years before you are able to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any browser that has currently implemented JavaScript 2.0. That might be why you cannot run it.

Comment: The AVM2 (FlashPlayer 9+ has implementend EcmaScript 4, which should have become JavaScript 2)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.5 (which you said you are using in a comment) [supports JavaScript 1.8.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/firefox_3.5_for_developers#New_JavaScript_features), so any JS 2 features will not be supported.

Answer (score -3):

just an internal function will be enough as below:

```
function Car (make, model, year, color) {
    this.Make = make;
    this.Model = model;
    this.Year = year;
    this.Color = color;
    this.FullName = this.Year + " " + "<b>" + this.Make + "</b> " + this.Model;
}

var mySUV = new Car("Toyota", "4Runner SR5",2001, "Thundercloud");
document.write ("I drive a " + mySUV.FullName);
```

Comment: Is this way more efficient than using functions?

Comment: That code is neither ECMAScript 4 or 6. That's a botched up object literal.

Comment: owch. That was a botched up object literal if I ever saw one myself. However, a better answer has since been plagarised from @PiPeep's answer.